# How to make an efficient use of the xml:lang attribue?

Tags: xml, lang

While reading XML specs I saw that XML has two builtin attributes, one of them being `xml:lang`.

I understood that let user define the language of the current block but how can it be used by XML consumer's programs ?

Can internet browser map the system local and the `xml:lang` attribute value ?
What will be the difference of using `xml:lang="en"` instead of `lang="en"` ?

I don't know if I could make myself clear, but if someone has an example of use of the `xml:lang` atribute, please share.

Answer (score 1):

`xml:lang` has the same purpose as `lang` - it defines the language a document or fragment is written in. Two different attributes are necessary because not all HTML is XML, and not all XML is (X)HTML.

Use cases:

- If the XML describes a text document,
  a word processor could select the
  appropriate dictionary . `te` in
  English meant probably `the`, but
  it's a French word.
- A browser (web,
  help, or similar) could offer to
  automatically translate the content
  if it's not in the list of the
  languages the user understands (in
  fact, that's what Chrome does).
- The
  attribute could also prevent a
  code-heavy site from mistakenly being
  classified as English by search
  engines.

Answer (score 0):

> I understood that let user define the language of the current block but how can it be used by XML consumer's programs ?

The prime examples are for search engines to promote content in the searcher's known languages higher than other content and for screen readers to switch to a pronunciation library for the language the content is in.

> Can internet browser map the system local and the xml:lang attribute value ?

Most browsers don't care. Screen readers do, but if they use the system local language then it is generally as a default of the document doesn't override it.

> What will be the difference of using xml:lang="en" instead of lang="en" ?

The former is a generic XML way of specifying the language. The later is an HTML specific way.

In HTML documents, the lang attribute has much better support.